# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "my.url" No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, web-services

I got an error of UnknownHostException.

```
 try{
           httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
           String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString((params[0] + ":" + params[1]).getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.NO_WRAP);

           HttpGet request = new HttpGet("my.url");
           request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
           request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");

           client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

           /*in the next line is when the exception is launched*/
           response = client.execute(request);

           userAuth = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

           return true;
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           return false;
       }
```

I also give Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Any idea about how to resolve the problem?

Comment: where you declared your my.url ?

Comment: where is your URL??? and what is it???

Comment: @KingofMasses "my.url" is the url of the webservice (http://xxxxx/api/login)

Comment: @Devraj It's the url of the web service.